# Why do the "Tags" and "Users" show the mobile version in SE for PC?

Tags: feature-request, responsive-design, users-page, tags-page

I saw posts which state the **Tags** and **Users** page are not available in the mobile site.
But these pages show an option to switch to the mobile version. Obviously there is not change in the interface, before and after clicking it.

If I click that option and surf in other pages, they're available in the mobile version. Also, clicking this **Mobile** option once doesn't show an option as **Full site** in these pages. So, if one clicks this option, they may not know whether the current site is in mobile or full-site version. Yes, they can go to pages other than **Tags** and **Users** and check.

**But as the mobile version isn't available for these pages, can this option be removed from them or can these be made responsive? (as Luuklag pointed out)**

[image]

Comment: I don't think removing them from the footer, which **should be uniform** across all pages is the solution here. The solution would be to make those pages responsive.